# How to highlight the whole button when hovering over CSS Grid item?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm building a navbar for my website, and I'm using CSS grid because I learned it recently and I want to get more comfortable with it. I am trying to get the whole button to change formatting when I hover over it, however, when I hover over the link it only changes the link's background. This is what my navbar's CSS looks like:

```
#navbar-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 75px / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #374457;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif
}
```

I tried changing the height of the div to be 100%, so that it would stretch from the top to the bottom of the navbar. This works in terms of making the button highlight, but this pushes the text to the top of the div, and I've tried many things but I can't fix this. This is what item 2's CSS looks like:

```
#item-2{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 30px; 
}

#item-2:hover{
  color:inherit;
  background-color: #686671;
}
```

I've replicated my problem at https://codepen.io/kadhirumasankar/pen/rEBgLp. Some of the items are oddly colored, but they're to help me see what's going on. Item 2 is the one that I changed the height of, and I've only changed Item 3's background color.

If you could just find a way to make the text in Item 2 center vertically it would solve my problem. Also, if you think any parts of my CSS are unnecessary, please let me know. It will help me develop better practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i modified your code to get it working.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBbxvJ

You can compare the changes side by side but basicaly i removed

```
justify-items: center;
align-items: center;
```

from #navbar-grid
and added a few changes to your anchors.
Quick tip for your: try to avoid changing anchors parents background to show active or hover states. It all should happen with the anchor tag.

Comment: That works! Thank you very much. I'll keep that in mind for the future